# comparison with strings having white space

Tags: java, string-comparison

Sorry if it's a silly question. I need to compare with a name which has three words separated by one white space. If the name is null or "This is Android" i would do something, otherwise i do something else. For example, is the following code right to do this comparison?

```
 if((name==null)||(name.equalsIgnoreCase("This is Android")))
     { 
      //start activity 1
      }
    else 
      {
        //start activity 2
       }
```

Comment: please include little more details about 'name'

Comment: "three words separated by one white space" how?

Comment: sorry name is a string already. i edited my question.thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check if the `name` is null before you do that, otherwise it looks good. (except for, it should be `if` instead of `If`):

```
//either
if(name != null) {
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("This is Android") {

    }
}

//or
if("This is Android ".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
```

**Update:**

When you are comparing strings, the whitespaces count. So, basically "Hello world" and "Hello world " are not equal.

You need to use the `.trim()` method to ignore the surrounding whitespaces.

```
name = name.trim(); //since strings are immutable you need to assign return value to name
if("This is Android".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
```

Comment: Why do you go toString on a String literal? Also, why invert the order?

Comment: @Miquel: Thanks for spotting. Did not pay attention while copy from OP. If you invert if the null check is not required so.

Comment: @gurung - unless there is a need, you do not need to check for null. That is covered by the equalsIgnoreCase call.

Comment: @ChrisAldrich: That does not make any sense. Suppose: `name` is null then how is `equalsIgnoreCase` going to cover `name.equalsIgnoreCase`??? It's that simple.

Comment: I would **never use** `string != null string.equals("literal")` and its variants. It's bad practice and it should not be even mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

"This is Android " is different from "This is Android" and `equalsIgnoreCase` will return false. You can use `trim()` to remove spaces and the start or the end of the `String`s.

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually "This is Android" in the code. is what i meant...edited my question again..sorry for the typo.

Comment: Then the answer is yes. The comparison is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Always keep constant String on left hand side in equals, this ensures no NPE:

like this :

```
if ("This is Android ".equalsIgnoreCase(str1)) {
    // start activity 1
} else {
    // start activity 2
}
```

In case you dont want space then add `trim()`:

```
if ("This is Android ".trim().equalsIgnoreCase(str1)) {
     // start activity 1
} else {
     // start activity 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if("This is Android".equalsIgnoreCase(name))
    // start activity 1
} else {
    // start activity 2
}
```

or the bullet-proof (in case user pasted value with unwanted spaces at the end of string)

```
if(name != null && "This is Android".equalsIgnoreCase(name.trim()))
    // start activity 1
} else {
    // start activity 2
}
```